# Why is a bad pointer being passed into my native exported methods from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, code-injection

This is my C# code:

```
    [DllImport("Tomb.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe uint InjectManualMap(ulong pId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPCStr)]string dllPath);
```

and for whatever reason when I attempt to use my C++ code:

```
extern "C" DllExport unsigned int StdCall InjectManualMap(unsigned long pid, const char* dllPath) {
     ManualMapInjector* mmp = new ManualMapInjector;
     std::string dll(dllPath);
     unsigned int kk = mmp->Inject(pid, dll);
     delete mmp;
     return kk;
}
```

the const char* dllPath is always a bad pointer (0x000000000).
I'm not sure what's happening here, because all other solutions point to using either a StringBuilder (tested it, did the same thing), or using MarshalAs which is something the current code I have posted does.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you keep `string`, but remove the `MarshalAsAttribute`? The examples I saw that supposedly worked, were not using `MarshalAs`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens, sadly. I can't get it to work any which way.

Comment: Could be an issue with what you are passing in for your `dllPath`. There were some decent suggestions on this page that I didn't see mentioned elsewhere -- http://manski.net/2012/06/pinvoke-tutorial-passing-strings-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that C# `long` is 64 bits wide, but C++ `long`, on Windows, is 32 bits wide. The pinvoke should be:

```
[DllImport("Tomb.dll")]
public static extern uint InjectManualMap(uint pId, string dllPath);
```

Note that I also removed the `unsafe` directive and the `MarshalAs` attribute which are not needed.

Comment: Thanks. You might like to accept the answer. I know you are new here which is why I mention it.

Comment: I didn't realize where the button was! I come to stackoverflow all the time, but I never registered until now. 
Thanks again for your help! :)