# passing string from C++/CLI class library to C#

Tags: c#, string, dll, c++-cli

I wrote a class library in VS 2010 C++/CLI and created a dll.

```
// testclass.h
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace test
{
    public ref class testclass
    {
      public:
         std::string getstringfromcpp()
         {
            return "Hello World";   
         }
    };
}
```

And I want to use it in C# program, add this dll to reference then:

```
using test;
... 
testclass obj = new testclass();
textbox1.text = obj.getstringfromcpp();
...
```

What should I do with this issue?

Comment: i cant understand in c++ to c# direction, c++ foo function return void? how can i give this string in c#?

Comment: What are you talking about? What `foo()`?  Other than that, whats the problem with your code above?  It looks like it should work

Comment: can you explain it with sample "hello world" and use it in textbox in c#?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't _understand_ the above code rather than _that there may be a bug in it_?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx

Comment: @X-TECH I don't think that duplicate applies because the above example is  **C++/CLI**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example
i cant understand what should i use this code

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.  `foo()` is from other page

Comment: @user3778594 _"i cant understand what should i use this code"_ - I think ignore that page.  It is not relevant to your code above as you are using c++/CLI.  Please refer to the MSDN link I posted

Comment: Really passing a string from a c++ dll to c# has not a simple way?

Comment: @nvoigt - the duplicate you chose is particularly bad and doesn't apply to this question. OP uses C++/CLI, not plain C++.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski oh, indeed. He managed to hide it quite well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an interop scenario, you need to return a string object you'll be able to read from .NET code.

Don't return a `std::string` (there is no such thing in C#) or a `const char *` (readable from C# but you'd have to manage memory deallocation) or things like that. Return a `System::String^` instead. This is the *standard* string type in .NET code.

This will work:

```cpp
public: System::String^ getStringFromCpp()
{
    return "Hello World";   
}
```

But if you actually have a `const char *` or `std::string` object you'll have to use the `marshal_as` template:

```cpp
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
```

```cpp
public: System::String^ getStringFromCpp()
{
    const char *str = "Hello World";
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(str);
}
```

Read [Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) for more details.

---

To convert a `System::String^` to `std::string` you can also use the `marshal_as` template, as explained in the above link. You just need to include a different header:

```cpp
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

```cpp
System::String^ cliStr = "Hello, World!";
std::string stdStr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(cliStr);
```

Comment: wow, it works fine at last. very very very thank you dear Lucas.
Would you kindly explain about other direction? send a string from c# and use it as std:string in c++?

Comment: @user3778594 I added that to the answer

Comment: I involved with this issue for 2 days, I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

In my program somehow it refuses to convert the std::string directly to System::String^ but takes the char* casting  ==>  std::string.c_str()

```
public: System::String^ getStringFromCpp()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(str.c_str());
}
```