# C from C#: string as parameter and return value?

Tags: c#, .net, c, interop

I'm calling the `doThis` function in a `.c` file in a Win32 DLL.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) double doThis( char *message)
{
    printf("do nothing much");
    return 32.5;
}
```

using this calling code:

```
[DllImport(@"\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\c-sharp\Hot\MusicIO\Debug\HelloWorld.dll", 
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double doThis(string message);


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double returned = doThis("what 2");
    MessageBox.Show("Click " + returned);
}
```

That works fine, but I want the function to return a `char *`... and return the `message` variable.

When I change the `doThis` to return a `char *`, and the calling code to expect a `string`, the Win32 Host crashes at runtime.

**Any advice?**

[weirdly, I think I had this working just before]

Comment: So I'm changing declaration to `__declspec(dllexport) char *doThis( char *message)` and then returning the `message`...  on the calling side, `        public static extern string doThis(string message);`...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example)

Comment: Thanks @4566976, useful but I'm very glad to have the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose for a while this signature worked:

```
__declspec(dllexport) char* doThis(char* message)
```

You call it from C# and then you have a `char*`. You copy it over to a `string`, and then... then *what?* What do you do with that `char*`?

Do you call `free` on it? The `free` of *which* C runtime library by the way? Or maybe you shouldn't since the pointer may be from static memory? You don't know, and the .NET mashaller doesn't know either.

---

The proper way to handle this is to pass a second `char*` parameter, that points to some buffer *you* allocated, and *you* are responsible for freeing.

Well, in C# that doesn't really have to be *you*. The marshaller can handle this for you.

So define a signature like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double doThis(char* message, char* output, int maxOutputLength)
```

The `maxOutputLength` parameter is a security measure, to let your C code know the maximum length of the message. Use it as you see fit in your C code.

Note: In C++ code, `message` would be a `const char*`, while `output` would remain a `char*`.

---

On the C# side, the signature would involve a `StringBuilder`:

```
[DllImport(@"HelloWorld.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double doThis(string message, StringBuilder output, int maxOutputLength);
```

Then, you allocate a `StringBuilder` with some initial capacity, and pass it that:

```
var output = new StringBuilder(1024);
double returned = doThis("what 2", output, output.Capacity);
var outputStr = output.ToString();
```

And the marshaller handles the plumbing for you.

Comment: Amazing answer with lots of amazing points, including the difference if it were C++ and the consideration of what you would do with the object once returned. Thank you.

Comment: One additional question: if it's an array of StringBuilder objects, could I pass... an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I don't think so. You could pass `char**` (or `IntPtr`) directly and manage the memory yourself, or you could use C++/CLI as an interop layer. P/Invoke works well only for the most common cases, for anything more complicated you'll have to do it yourself.