# Problem with string output in c# after exporting from c dll

Tags: c#, c, dll

I connected a dll to my c# code to return a string from it:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Dll_NIRS_API void realize(char*)
```

```
void realize(char* buf) 
{
...
    wstring full_text;
    // operations with full_text 

    char* fill = (char*)(full_text.c_str());
    strcpy(buf, fill);

}
```

Connecting to C#:

```
[DllImport("dll_name.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern void realize(StringBuilder text);
```

Then I use this function and put the resulting string in a textBox:

```
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(100);
            realize(text);
            textBox4.Text = text.ToString();
```

But instead of text:
РАЗВОРОТ(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4)
РАЗВОРОТ(1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4)
the textBox outputs this:
РАЗВОРОТ(듹翼

The "full_text" variable is filled in correctly, but I'm not sure about the "fill" variable, maybe the problem is in strcpy or in the dll export.
I use `StringBuilder` on the advice from this question: [Passing strings from C# to C++ DLL and back -- minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752001/passing-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-and-back-minimal-example)

**EDIT**
I partially solved the problem, now the entire text is displayed in the textBox (and not just part of it, as it was before). I just converted `full_text` from `wstring` to `string` for use in `strcpy`. I also changed the `CharSet.Unicode` to `CharSet.Ansi`. However, the text is now like this:
Р РђР—Р’РћР РћРў(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4)Р РђР—Р’РћР РћРў(1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4)

Comment: Does not `realize(text);` cause trouble as `void realize(char* buf)` expects a `char *` and not a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I found such a solution with ```stringBuilder``` to use strings from c dll in c#

Comment: @Daria If your comment means that you tried to follow an example you found somewhere, please [edit] your question and add a link to this example. Your C# prototype of function `realize` does not match the C++ prototype and implementation, so it is undefined behavior. Even if the memory of a `StringBuilder` object is compatible to a C string, there might be different encodings.

Comment: I edited the question and added a link

Comment: You would need to specify `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` or change the `buf` parameter to `wchar_t*`. Beware, your code is dangerous as `strcpy` will happily overwrite memory you did not allocate. Usually, you would pass another parameter to the C function specifying the maximum string size.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter I changed CharSet to CharSet.Ansi and converted ```full_text``` from ```wstring``` to ```string```. It got better, but I also see unusually symbols (I edited my question)

Comment: Encoding issue. Is your `string` perhaps in UTF8?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter yes, its UTF8. Should I change to UTF16? How I can do it?

Comment: If this is possible: yes. Then go back to CharSet.Unicode and wstring, but change the parameter to `wchar_t*` and `strcpy` to `wcscpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two (easy) string marshalling options using P/Invoke:

- Either declare `[CharSet = CharSet.Ansi]` in C# and have `char*` in C. This requires that the C library uses the "ANSI" character set, which seems not to be the case here.
- Or declare `[CharSet = CharSet.Unicode]` in C# and have `wchar_t*` in C

For the second option, the last statements should be:

```
wchar_t* fill = full_text.c_str();
wcscpy(buf, fill);
```

**Big caveat**: strcpy/wcscpy is **dangerous** as it may overwrite memory you did not allocate. I strongly recommend replacing it with:

```
wcscpy_s(buf, size, fill);
```

`size` would be the buffer size (max number of characters, including terminating NUL) and has to be passed ad additional parameter to the method.